# Can't place image next to text (pushed into next div)

Tags: html, css, image, position

I want to place an image next to some text inside a div but the image was pushed into the next div below and won't move up no matter how much I increase the margin or padding. I want the center of the image to be where the tip of the arrow is in the picture:

[Here's where the image is and where I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCHez.png)

Here's the CSS and HTML:

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #1919ff;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#about {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  height: 400px;
  width: 67%;
  margin: auto;
}
   
.round-border{
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
.portrait-image{
    width: 25%;    
    margin-bottom: 120%;
  }
h9 {
    font-size: 142%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 30%;
    padding-top: 12%;
    display: inline-block;
  
}
.header-bar{
    height: 3px;
    width: 51%;
    background: #272C31;
    margin-right: 23%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
h10 {
    font-size: 142%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 24%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#image position {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-botton: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style>
img {
    float: right;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;xxxxxxxxx</h2>
</div>

<body style="background-color: #5D6D7E;">
  <div id="about" align="center" position="relative">
    <h9><p align="right">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </h9>
    <div class="header-bar"></div>
    <h10><p align="right">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </h10>
    <div id="image position"><img class="portrait-image round-border" align="right" src="http://abload.de/img/gpuxh.png" alt="portrait">
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The div with class header outside body? To align text inside p use text-align not align. pParagraph inside h don't have sense.

Comment: can you please reduce the code such as only show the problem part

Comment: I reduced the code a little bit but the thing is I don't know where the problem is exactly. I think it might be the padding/margin of other elements that is blocking the image from moving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many things wrong with your code and I'm not sure where to begin. There are no h9 or h10 header tags. I would suggest using valid header tags and modifying the font-size according to your taste. Also, you can't have a class/id name separated by a space. So, "image position" will not work. Fixed it the best way I could.

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #1919ff;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#about {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  height: 400px;
  width: 67%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.round-border {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.portrait-image {
  width: 25%;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 51%;
  background: #272C31;
  margin-right: 23%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#image-position {
  float: right;
  margin: 15% 5% 0 0;
}

#text {
  float: left;
  width: 57%;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 5%;
}
.clearfix {
  /*clear the floats here*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body style="background-color: #5D6D7E;">
  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;xxxxxxxxx</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="clearfix">
    <div id="text">
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <div class="header-bar"></div>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </div>
    <img class="portrait-image round-border" id="image-position" src="http://abload.de/img/gpuxh.png" alt="portrait">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed pretty much everything. Only thing is the image is now touching the header and I want to move it slightly down but I can't, even when I modify the margin and padding. Picture: http://abload.de/img/websiteimage3rwjbd.png

Comment: `margin-top` on the img will work. I have added the same.

Comment: I tried many different values for margin-top or using the margin with the four values that you gave and the image is still stuck to the header. Even when I modify the image's width.

Comment: Can you confirm that your text and the img elements are siblings with a common parent? You can also debug the issue using Chrome debtor's.

Comment: I confirm that the "text" div and the image element are siblings with the common parent that is the "about" div. I know your fix should work because it looks perfect here when I run the code snippet, but when I run it on my HTML editor it creates this stuck-to-the-header problem.

Thank you for your help anyway, my problem is 99% fixed and with cleaner code so I really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually it works perfectly now, I just forgot to call the image class in the HTML, sorry about that. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS float. It is for elements that 'float' to the side of a text.

Try setting:

```
#image-position {
  /* ... Your css here */
  float: right;
}
```

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Comment: I use 'float: right' in the HTML style tag. I tried putting it in the CSS but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try putting the image outside the div id="about".

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap to achive this, try the below code snippet.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>
                Your text goes here... 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="">      
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps,

Comment: Tried it, the text becomes misaligned and the image gets shrunk and pushed way to the right: http://abload.de/img/websiteimage2aaore.png